# How to add selected class to home page (href="/")

Tags: jquery, menu, selecteditem, pathname

Well, I can add the selected class to my parent `li` item in menu by using

```
$(function(){
   var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
   if ( path )
     $('#main-menu a[href$="' + path + '"]').parent('li').addClass('selected');
});
```

But it doesn't work for my home page with `href="/"`. 
How can I change this function to **add selected class** to home page when it's active as well? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** based on the new information about your URL formats, I would go for this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#main-menu a').filter(function() {
        return this.href === location.href;
    }).parent('li').addClass('selected');
});
```

Using the `.filter` function and comparing the `.href` *property* does the check on the full URL, rather than on the relative URLs that can appear within the `href` *attribute*.

Comment: if I do that, finally all my parent li get selected class, not only li with href="/"

Comment: @moto do all your other href's also end with `/`, then ?  Perhaps you should be using "exact match", rather than "ends with" ?

Comment: yes, all of them end with /, like a href="/travel/", a href="/team/", and home page has a href="/"

Comment: @moto right, so if you just use `'href='` instead of `'href$='` I think it'll work.  Actually if you do that there's no need to take the substring at all, just use `location.pathname` directly.

Comment: Thank you, I tried you function, it works! but I guess I should write earlier that one of my li has external url a href="http://...", so now selected class has home page and blog page with external url.

Comment: In which case use `.href` instead of `.pathname` for both halves, and it'll check that the entire URL matches.  The advantage of using the `.href` _property_ of the `<a>` elements instead of the `href` _attribute_ is that it gets mapped to a whole URL, including the host part.

Comment: Thank you for you help, it was very useful. My final function (I don't know is it correct or not, but it works). $(function(){
    $('#main-menu a').filter(function() {
        return this.href === location.href;
    }).parent('li').addClass('selected');
if($(this).attr("href")=="http://blog.com")
$(this).removeClass("selected");
});